# SQL query to dynamically append columns with calculated values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a "data" table with date start/end values and another table with money values distinct by year and by columns referred to zone/use pair in data table.
I'd like to know SQL syntax to obtain the "result table" as the example below.
According to the dates (and so the years) each record is referred to and in which the coefficients x,y are valid (when date end is NULL it means the record and values within are still valid and need to be used), I'd like to append for each record one column with a calculated value for each year the record is valid.
In future, if I'd add new records to "money" table, I'd like the result table would append further column s with calculated values for each year added.
I hope the following example would clarify better my needs, thanks

table "money"

```
+------+----------+----------+
| year | usd_d2_r | usd_d2_c |
|      |          |          |
+======+==========+==========+
| 2017 | 1000     | 1500     |
+------+----------+----------+
| 2018 | 2500     | 2000     |
+------+----------+----------+
| 2019 | 3000     | 3000     |
+------+----------+----------+
```

table "data"

```
+----+------------+------------+------+-----+------+-----+
| id | date_start | date_end   | zone | use | x    | y   |
+====+============+============+======+=====+======+=====+
| 1  | 2003-02-31 | NULL       | d2   | r   | 0.12 | 0.2 |
+----+------------+------------+------+-----+------+-----+
| 2  | 2016-01-12 | 2017-12-11 | d2   | c   | 0.7  | 0.1 |
+----+------------+------------+------+-----+------+-----+
| 3  | 2018-02-01 | NULL       | d2   | c   | 1    | 1   |
+----+------------+------------+------+-----+------+-----+
```

table "results"

```
+----+------------+------------+------+-----+------+-----+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| id | date_start | date_end   | zone | use | x    | y   | val_2017       | val_2018       | val_2019       |
+====+============+============+======+=====+======+=====+================+================+================+
| 1  | 2003-02-31 | NULL       | d2   | r   | 0.12 | 0.2 | 1000*(formula) | 2500*(formula) | 3000*(formula) |
+----+------------+------------+------+-----+------+-----+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 2  | 2016-01-12 | 2017-12-11 | d2   | c   | 0.7  | 0.1 | 1500*(formula) | NULL           | NULL           |
+----+------------+------------+------+-----+------+-----+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 3  | 2018-02-01 | NULL       | d2   | c   | 1    | 1   | NULL           | 2500*(formula) | 3000*(formula) |
+----+------------+------------+------+-----+------+-----+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Called a pivot, and there are a multitude of ways to do it; PIVOT, conditional aggregation, repeated joins...

Comment: Who couuld show me one way to do It?